# How can I prove that $f$ doesn't have all real roots $\forall a\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

We have $f=x^4+ax^3+4x^2+1\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ with $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\in\mathbb{C}$.

We need to prove that $\color\red{\forall a\in\mathbb{C}},f$ doesn't have all real roots. How can I begin to solve this exercise.

---

Here is what I've tried:

$$\sum_{k=1}^4 x_k^2< 0\Rightarrow\:f\:doesn't\:have\:all\:real\:roots$$

- Therefore $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^4 x_k\right)^2-2\left(\sum_{1\leq k<i\leq 4}x_k x_i\right)=a^2-8$$

$\Rightarrow a^2-8<0\Rightarrow a\in(-\sqrt{8},\sqrt{8})$

> But what I proved was that $f$ doesn't have all real roots for $a\in(-\sqrt{8},\sqrt{8})$. I don't have ideea how can I prove that  $f$ doesn't have all real roots $\color\red{\forall a\in\mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: Start with the easy part. If $a\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$, can $f$ have a real zero?

Comment: @hHhh there is $x_i$ is something wrong?

Comment: @DanielFischer what you want to mean by a real zero?

Comment: A zero (root, but I prefer the term zero) that is an element of $\mathbb{R}$ (which means it is real, as opposed to e.g. purely imaginary).

Comment: @Lucas Daniel Fischer was asking you to have a look at the roots of $f$ in the case $a$ not in $ \mathbb{R}$...

Comment: @DanielFischer I suppose that the only real roots for $f$ are the divisors of 1: $\pm 1$

Comment: @Lucas There might a trick for this problem, but if you want to look at an automatic method to solve this kind of problems, the keyword is "the discriminant of the polynomial" (the roots of which are the values of the parameter $a$ where the number of real roots of $f$ may change)

Comment: Typically, neither of the two is a root, but for suitable $a$, $f$ has real roots.

Comment: because $\sum_{k=1}^{4}x^2_{k}<0$ then the roots are Purely Imaginary Number is a  part of complex number,so you can only prove $a\in(-\sqrt{8},\sqrt{8})$

Comment: such $a=-6$,then $x=1$ is roots,so you can understand the @DanielFischer meaning

Comment: I think that for all real $a$ such that $\lvert a\rvert > \sqrt{160/27 +112 \sqrt 7/27}$, f has two real roots. If $a$ is real and the absolute value of $a$ is less than this value, then $f$ has no real root.

Comment: @Lucas Another way to go would be first to follow Daniel Fischer's hint for the case $a$ is nonreal, then look at Descartes' rule of signs for the case where $a$ is real.

Answer (score 4):

Since $0$ is not a root, we can as well consider the “reverse” polynomial
$$
g(x)=x^4+4x^2+ax+1
$$
whose roots are the reciprocals of the roots of $f$.

If $g$ has four distinct real roots, its derivative must vanish in three points; now
$$
g'(x)=4x^3+8x+a
$$
and the second derivative must vanish in two distinct points; but
$$
g''(x)=12x^2+8
$$
has no real root.

This also settles the case of multiple roots, of course (with just a bit of work).

Comment: Clear-cut and convincing, unlike the other incomplete answers so far

Comment: egreg this is not similar with derivative for multiple root of order 4?

Comment: @Lucas It's impossible for the equation to have a root of multiplicity $4$.

Comment: @egreg I don't understand how you figure out that "If g has four distinct real roots, its derivative must vanish in three points;"

Comment: @Lucas Rolle's theorem applied to the interval between two consecutive roots.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case $a>0$. Then $f$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, so there are no positive zeros. Thus, if $f$ had four real zeros, they would have to be negative, and then by Rolle's theorem, $f'$ would have to have three negative zeros. But $f'(0)=0$, so...

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a start.

If $a$ is complex, there are no real zeros. So we'll assume $a$ real.

Given any polynomial with $n$ real zeros, $f'(x)$ has at least $n-1$ real zeros, $f''(x)$ has $n-2$ real zeros, etc.

In this case, the second derivative is:

$$12x^2+6ax+8$$

which, by dividing by by $3$, has the same number of roots as:

$$4x^2+2ax+\frac{8}{3}= \left(2x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{8}{3}-\frac{a^2}{4}$$

So you need $\frac{a^2}{4}>\frac{8}{3}$ or $|a|>\sqrt{\frac{32}{3}}$ to have two real roots for the second derivative.